# Systemd breaks usbmount

Tags: systemd

I use the [usbmount](https://packages.qa.debian.org/u/usbmount.html) package in Debian.
This package is currently broken in stable and also unstable because of
the issue described in [usbmount: Can't mount ntfs drive (Transport endpoint is not connected)](https://bugs.debian.org/774149) and was also [removed from testing](https://packages.qa.debian.org/u/usbmount/news/20150604T163911Z.html).

Christian Weinberger submitted a patch that fixes the issue - I verified that. However I don't really understand the issue or the fix, except that it is connected with systemd. So I have the following questions:

1. Please explain the breakage to me in simple terms. I don't know
   much about systemd or related things.
2. Please explain what Christian's fix is doing, and whether it is the
   correct fix for the issue. If not, why not?